# Data annotation for int?[] property using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, data-annotations

I have a C# property as mentioned below:

```
public int?[] SubType { get; set; }
```

It forms one of the parameter for an API call in the application. It is very much possible that one can form a API call without setting any values for this parameter in which case it should be assigned with null value as mentioned in the example below:

HTTP POST request object:

```
{
  "countries": [],
  "tagIds": [],
  "pattern": "abc",
  "limit": 5,
  "offset": 0
}
```

Now in case someone provided value for this parameter then in that case I am looking for the following requirements:

1. Min value should be 1 and Max value should be 9
2. None of the value should be negative

For example: Valid request

```
{
    "countries":[],
    "tagIds":[],
    "pattern":"abc",
    "subType:[1,9], 
    "limit":5,
    "offset":0  
}
```

Invalid request:

```
{
    "countries":[],
    "tagIds":[],
    "pattern":"abc",
    "subType":[-1,100]  
    "limit":5,
    "offset":0  
}
```

Can anyone help me to know with some sample example how to fix this issue?

Comment: By `public int?[] SubType { get; set; }`, do you mean an array containing nullable ints?  Or, an array (which may be present or not (i.e. null)) containing ints?  You don't show any example of the former (for example `"subType" : [ null, 1, 2]`

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57 for your response.  It is possible that this property can be excluded completely since it is a optional property. Again this property if included should contain values between 1 to 9 only. I have mentioned about the API request in my question already.

Comment: Arrays are reference types, so they are always nullable.  I don't have a clue how to do declarable validation on the values within it.

Comment: By the way, in case I wasn't clear, `public int?[] SubType { get; set; }` is declaring an array (which is nullable because all arrays are nullable) of nullable integers, the same as `public Nullable<int>[] SubType { get; set; }`  You probably just want an array of int: `public int[] SubType { get; set; }`

Comment: I want to have a property of int[] which is optional. Hence I thought of having it as  public int?[] SubType { get; set; }. In this case it is very much possible that I can have value for SubType. There is another possibility to have no values and hence I made it as nullable.

Comment: This: `public int?[] SubType { get; set; }` is an array of nullable ints (and, since all arrays are nullable, it's optional too).  All you want is `public int[] SubType { get; set; }`; an array of ints - again, it's nullable since it's an array..

Answer (score 0):

I added a custom data annotation and used at the model class level as mentioned below:
// ValidateArticleSubTypeAttribute.cs

```
public sealed class ValidateArticleSubTypeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object subType, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Since SubType is null, hence allow null
        int? [] arrSubType = subType as int? [];
        if (arrSubType == null || arrSubType.Length == 0)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        // Validation for negative numbers
        bool allPositive = arrSubType.All(s => s > 0);
        if (!allPositive)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Enter only positive values between 1 and 9");
        }

        // Validation for Min and Max value of the SubType array
        var min = arrSubType.Min();
        var max = arrSubType.Max();
        if (min < 1 || max > 9)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Enter only positive values between 1 and 9");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Use at the model class:

```
public class SampleSearchDTO
{
    [ValidateArticleSubType()]
    public int? [] SubType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This solution worked for me.